# python unittest inheritance - abstract test class

Tags: python, unit-testing

I need to use `unittest` in python to write some tests. I am testing the behavior of 2 classes, `A` and `B`, that have a lot of overlap in behavior because they are both subclasses of `C`, which is abstract. I would really like to be able to write 3 testing classes: `ATestCase`, `BTestCase`, and `AbstractTestCase`, where `AbstractTestCase` defines the common setup logic for `ATestCase` and `BTestCase`, but does not itself run any tests. `ATestCase` and `BTestCase` would be subclasses of `AbstractTestCase` and would define behavior/input data specific to `A` and `B`.

Is there a way to create an abstract class via python `unittest` that can take care of setup functionality by inheriting from TestCase, but not actually run any tests?

Comment: Why don't you test `C`, rather than testing the same functionality in `A` and `B`? Alternatively, `TestCase` could be a mix-in to the test cases for `A` and `B`, so that the `AbstractTestCase` isn't actually discovered by `unittest`.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, construct like that will surely work:

```
class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass  # common teardown

    def tearDown(self):
        pass  # common teardown


class ATestCase(BaseTestCase):
    def test1(self):
        pass


class BTestCase(BaseTestCase):
    def test1(self):
        pass
```

If knowledge from `ATestCase` or `BTestCase` is required in `BaseTestCase` simply override some method in subclasses but use it in superclass.

```
class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.instance = self._create_instance()

    def _create_instance(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()


class ATestCase(BaseTestCase):
    def _create_instance(self):
        return A()


class BestCase(BaseTestCase):
    def _create_instance(self):
        return B()
```

Note that if any `test_(self)` methods will be implemented in BaseTestCase, they'll run (and fail due to failing setUp) when discovered by automated runners.

As a workaround you may use `skipTest` in your setUp clause in abstract test and override it in subclasses.

```
class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.instance = self._create_instance()

    def _create_instance(self):
        self.skipTest("Abstract")

    def test_fromBase(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

Note that skipping `test_fromBase` (e.g. via decorator) won't be good, since 'test should be skipped' logic will be inherited by all subclasses.

Comment: I skipped in `setUp` by checking the class: `if self.__class__ == BaseTestCase: self.skipTest("Skip base class")`

Answer (score 2):

I tried Łukasz’s answer and it works, but I don’t like `OK (SKIP=<number>)` messages.  For my own desires and aims for having a test suite I don’t want me or someone to start trusting any particular number of skipped tests, or not trusting and digging into the test suite and asking why something was skipped, and always?, and on purpose?  For me that’s a non-starter.

I happen to use nosetests exclusively, and by convention test classes starting with `_` are not run, so naming my base class `_TestBaseClass` is sufficient.

I tried this in Pycharm with Unittests and py.test and both of those tried to run my base class  and its tests resulting in errors because there’s no instance data in the abstract base class. Maybe someone with specific knowledge of either of those runners could make a suite, or something, that bypasses the base class.